# Socket.io gives Welcome to socket.io message

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is my server

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Here is my client index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Here are my commaneds

```
node server.js
```

and on browser I am hitting URL `localhost:80/index.html`

after hitting above URL I am getting message 
Welcome to socket.io.

I am using nodeJS v0.10.9

Comment: Ok, Cool! What do you want from us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.io` provides a `socket.io` server, not a web server. So `index.html` in the context of `socket.io` doesn't exist.

Instead, you could use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) to provide a basic web server, combined with `socket.io` to provide messaging:

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(80);
```

```
// ./public/index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect(); // let socket.io autodiscover the server
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```